# Changing PerformancePoint Dashboard page to be Publishing Page?

Tags: css, branding, publishing, publishing-page, performancepoint

Is there any way to make the PerformancePoint Dashboard page (the page where you can see your charts, scorecards etc.) to a publishing page. Currently I believe its a web part page and my CSS is not being applied (works on rest of site just not this individual page). What would be the best way around this? All my sites are publishing sites and the CSS works fine, just this one page doesn't want to apply the CSS.

Thanks for any help! 
Tudor

Comment: anyone offer any help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't really find a solution to apply my CSS to the page directly, but what I ended up doing, and works quite well, is to create a new Publishing page and user PerformancePoint web parts to display my Scorecards and Reports on the page.

Now all my CSS is being applied and everything seems to be working well.